# Thought Experiment - Stationary Electron and Moving Observer

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, special-relativity, quantum-electrodynamics

Several years ago I heard of this problem (perhaps in Jackson's electrodynamics book?), but I don't recall the details.  I was thinking about it and cannot make sense of what is going on. I am hoping someone here can elucidate.

Imagine you have an electron floating in space by itself, stationary.  Now imagine an observer zooms by it at a speed of $v$.  In the rest frame of the observer, it is observing an electron speeding by at velocity $-v$.  Because this electron always emits an electric field, this "moving" electron will in turn create a magnetic field due to its "motion" (One can think of this moving electron as a very small current).  But in the rest frame of the stationary electron, there is no such magnetic field.

This is very puzzling to me because the field does not exist in all frames according to this construction.  Can anyone provide any insight into what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Both fields electric and magnetic are unified into one electromagnetic field (See [Electromagnetic tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor)). Electric and magnetic fields are just description of the same beast from two different views.

This is analogical to 2D vector (1,1) having x component 1 and y component 1 in certain frame of reference (basis), but if you choose another, rotated by 45 degrees, it will have just one with length $\sqrt{2}$. But it is the same vector, just viewed differently.

Answer (score 1):

The fields aren’t observables, *per se*, since as you noticed they aren’t Lorentz invariant. What *is* invariant are the forces and torques imposed on charges by those fields. So as you boost from one frame to another, some of the electric field will transform to magnetic field and vice versa. But if you do a careful accounting of the forces generated by those fields in each frame, you’ll find they are identical.

Comment: Lorentz covariance is enough for observables and the fields _are_ observable. Forces are also covariant and not invariant.

Comment: I am interesting in working through this kind of calculation, namely, accounting of the forces in the different frames.  If you know of any source I can review that does this for a similar example, please kindly send my way.

Comment: @my2cts thank you for the corrections to tighten my language. Regarding whether the fields are observable, I agree that they are, but only in the sense that we measure their effects on charges, currents, polarizations, and magnetizations, hence my qualifier.

Comment: @user41178 Take a look at the letter “Trouble with the Lorentz Law of Force: Incompatibility with Special Relativity and Momentum Conservation” M. Mansuripur, Physical Review Letters 108, 193901 (2012), which does essentially this calculation. However, the conclusion that the Lorentz form of force does not conserve momentum is only sort of correct. There were a lot of comments written  about this letter pointing out that the author forgot the “hidden momentum”, which is also interesting to read about.

Answer (score 1):

The electric and magnetic fields are very similar to, respectively, the centrifugal and Coriolis forces on a rotating disc. An observer who is located outside the disc at rest WRT it detects no Coriolis force except a centrifugal one that tends to throw the particle, tossed at an initial velocity $v$, outside the plate. However, an observer located on the disc, besides a centrifugal force, detects a Coriolis effect that tends to make the path of the tossed particle curved.

Remember that the induced magnetic field in your example is very similar to the Coriolis force since both of them depend on the instantaneous velocity of the particle, and the fields vectors are both perpendicular to the curved path of the particle. Pondering over this comparison may help you to better understand how is it possible for a specific observer to detect a field, whereas it is not detectable from the standpoint of another inertial observer.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, consider a bunch of electrons arranged in a line of constant linear charge density, $\lambda$. It's easy to show that (in standard cylindrical coordinates):

$$ \vec E = \frac{\lambda }{2\pi\rho\epsilon_0}\hat{\rho} $$

and

$$ \vec B = 0$$

Now have the linear charge moving at

$$\vec v= -v\hat z$$

then the electric field increases b/c of length contraction:

$$ \vec E' = \frac{\gamma\lambda }{2\pi\rho\epsilon_0}\hat{\rho} =\gamma\vec E$$

and the current

$$\vec j'= \lambda'\vec v = - \gamma\lambda v \hat z $$

leads to a magnetic field:

$$ \vec B' = -\frac{\gamma\lambda v\mu_0}{2\pi\rho}\hat{\theta} $$

Note that this exactly agrees with the Lorentz transformation of EM fields:

$$ \vec E'_{\perp} = \gamma( \vec E_{\perp} + \vec v \times \vec B_{\perp})= \gamma \vec E_{\perp}$$

$$ \vec B'_{\perp} = \gamma (\vec B_{\perp} - \frac{\vec v}{c^2} \times \vec E_{\perp})= -\gamma  \frac v {c^2} \frac{\lambda }{2\pi\rho\epsilon_0}(\hat z \times \hat{\rho})= -\frac{\gamma v \lambda \mu_0}{2\pi\rho} \hat{\theta}$$

with all field parallel to $\vec v $ being $0$.